# router.get firstname and last name

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use MongoDB and schema looks like this

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName :{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    lastName :{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email : {
        type:Array
    }
})
```

It is simple and correct. However, how can I fetch the data by using a first name and last name at the same time?
Thanks

```
router.get('/:firstname' , async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        dp = await User.findOne({"firstName" : req.params.firstname})
        res.status(201).json({person : dp})
    }catch(e){
        return res.status(500).json({message : e.message})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it like below example

```
router.get('/:firstname/:lastname' , async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        dp = await User.findOne({firstname : req.params.firstname, lastName : req.params.lastname})
        res.status(201).json({person : dp})
    }catch(e){
        return res.status(500).json({message : e.message})
    }
})
```